# showing property lines in Google Maps with Hybrid or Satellite view

Tags: maps, hybrid, satellite

Google maps will show property lines if you're sufficiently zoomed in and looking at the map view (in certain areas). But switching it to either hybrid or satellite view clears all the property lines. Is there a way to create a map that will still show the property lines when switching to hybrid or satellite view?